# Preventing Numerical value from being evaluated

Tags: evaluation, numerics

I have searched stackoverflow (and comparable pages) for quite a while now (got redirected from there to this specialized stack), and I surrender. I am trying to evaluate an expression that is small in the end numerically.

Example:

```
Log[Log[Log[6^5^4^3^2^1]]]=12.9525...
```

WolframAlpha has no problem evaluating these values for (any/a very high) amount of exponents (I tried it up to 20). I guess it is possible to achieve this in Mathematica aswell?

I tried Hold, Defer etc, as described in 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616592/mathematica-unevaluated-vs-defer-vs-hold-vs-holdform-vs-holdallcomplete-vs-etc

Hoever none of these did what I hoped for. Is it a matter of explaining Mathematica the rules of logarithms?

```
FullSimplify[Log[x^b], x>0 && b>0]
```

expands it nicely, however that is not what I want (I have explicit numbers).
Is there any way to perform the calculations WolframAlpha performs with mathematica (obviously avoiding the WolframAlpha Output Operator ;)) ?

Is there some Option/Assumption etc I have overlooked?

---

For this specific question there is a recursive algebraic solution: 
$$
n^{(n-1)^{...^1}}=e^{\log(n)*(n-1)^{...^1}}
$$
and so on, remove a bunch of e-s at the end.
I guess Wolfram|Alpha uses this. I would still like to know if theres a true Mathematica solution to this.

Comment: `tt = Log[Log[Log[6^5^4^3^2^1]]] // HoldForm;` and `tt /. Log[a_^b_] -> b Log[a] // Release // N` does provide you with the answer?

Comment: Probably not quite what you are looking for, but maybe a start:

PowerExpand[Log[Log[Log[a^b^c^d^e^f]]]] /. {a -> 6, b -> 5, c -> 4, 
  d -> 3, e -> 2, f -> 1}

Comment: @chris, oh yes it does, problem consists of something else now (see below); thank you!

Comment: I posted a related question on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/216937/2731)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you could do:

```
rules = {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^k_] :> k Log[x]};
N[Defer@Log[Log[Log[6^5^4^3^2^1]]] //. rules]
(*
--> 12.9525
*)
```

But you should be aware that it doesn't work ad-infinitum because your expression stops transforming after you get to

$\log \left(\log (5) 4^{3^{2^1}}+\log (\log (6))\right)$

**Edit**

I posted a related question in [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216937/2731) (no full answer yet)

Comment: Works wonderfully! The Problem got delayed a bit (but hey, thanks for your help!). I have n^...^1 defined as a function a[n_]:=n^a[n-1]
ofcourse, this wont expand to 6^5^4^3^2^1 for a[6], instead it will produce an overflow. I will have to try to get a[6] to evaluate to the Power tower and then I should be fine

Comment: That wasnt too hard lol:
b[n_]:=HoldForm[n]^b[n-1] great success!
Damn, Problem still not solved. For n>=8, I still receive overflows. -.-

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be

```
Block[{Power, Log},
 Log[Log[Log[6^5^4^3^2^1]]] // PowerExpand]
```

> Log[262144 Log[5] + Log[Log[2] + Log[3]]]

```
% // N
```

> 12.9525

Still gives overflows, it's equivalent to @belisarius's

Also,

```
Log[Log[Log[6^5^4^3^2^1]]] // Hold // PowerExpand // ReleaseHold
```